# multidimensional object building in javascript using loops

Tags: javascript, jquery, object, loops

So i have a html layout in which there are **blocks** (there are no fix number of them, because they can be created dynamically).

In these **blocks** there are **boxes** (again, they can be created dynamically)
The **boxes** contain *html element*s and also have different *data attributes*

So i need to create an object which looks like this

```
    block1 = {
       box1 : {
          id : box1.data('id'),
          content : box1.html()
       },
       box2 : {
          id : box2.data('id'),
          content : box2.html()
       } 
     },
     block2 = {
       box3 : {
          id : box3.data('id'),
          content : box3.html()
       }           
     }
```

Please don't write that the syntax is not correct, i know. I just tried to somehow illustrate what i want.

So my question is how do i do this with the help of jQuery?

Thank you in advanced

Comment: Are you trying to create HTML, or create JavaScript objects from HTML that already exists, or create HTML from these JavaScript objects?  I'm not exactly sure what you're asking.

Comment: @EricGalluzzo i'm trying to create JavaScript object from HTML

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can select all blocks and boxes and iterate over each of them using [`.each` *<sup>[docs]</sup>*](http://api.jquery.com/each/):

```
var blocks = {};

$('.block').each(function(index) {
    var boxes = {};
    $(this).find('.box').each(function(index) {
        boxes['box' + index] = {
            id: $(this).data('id');
            content: $(this).html();
        };
    });
    blocks['block' + index] = boxes;
});
```

You might not need an object of objects though, maybe an array of array suffices or would be even better, depending on what you intend to do with the data.

To learn more about how objects work, have a look at [MDN - Working with Object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects).

Comment: Thank you @Felix Kling i will test it know, but it looks like what i want

Answer (score 1):

Here is an idea:

1- Iterate over all of the blocks using some CSS selector.

2- Create a generic JS object and set a collection attribute called "boxes" to be an array

3- For each one, iterate over all the boxes inside it, again, using some CSS selector.

4- Create a generic JS object for each box and set the attributes as needed.

**Code version**
I think something like this would work (not tested):

```
var blocks = new Array();
$(".blocks").each(function(b) {
  var my_block = {boxes: new Array()};
  var $block = $(b);
  $(".box", $block).each(function(box) {
     var $box = $(box);
     my_block.boxes.push({id: $box.attr("id"), content: $box.html()});
  });
  blocks.push(my_block);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at Knockout.js, it's very comfortable to build an application like yours.

In detail: use Objects. Build an array for yourself, containing Objects with e.g. Block Name and all Child nodes.

```
<div id="lanesContainer" data-bind="foreach: blocks">
    <div id="" class="dropLane laneDefault ui-widget-header ui-dialog ui-widget ui-corner-all ui-front ui-resizable">
      <div class="ui-dialog-titlebar ui-helper-clearfix" data-bind="drop: {value: $data.dropTask}">
        <p class="laneheader" data-bind="text: $data.title">Lane</p>                  
      </div>

      <ul data-bind="foreach: box">
        <li class="ui-dialog-content laneItem" data-bind="drag: {value: $data}">
            <div class="ui-widget-header laneItemHeader" data-bind="text: $data.Title"></div>
            <div class="ui-widget-content laneItemBody" data-bind="text: $data.Description"></div>
            <div class="ui-widget-content laneItemFooter">
                <div class="ui-corner-all ui-state-default notification-important">
                    <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-notice" title="sometitle" data-bind="css: {'notification-important-hide': !$root.isElementImportant($data) }"></span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Is this useful?

Here is how to get an Object with nested Array of Childs:

```
function laneObject(title) {
    var obj = new Object();
    obj.title = title; //Identifier for Lane
    obj.childs = []; //Elements of Lane to display
    return obj;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not entirely sure of what your question is, but if you want to create blocks and boxes dynamically, I suggest you first of all use Arrays.

```
//All dynamically created blocks
blocks = [];

//Create blocks
for(var i = 1; i < 3; i++) {
    var block = {
        //All dynamically generated bloxes
        boxes = [];
    };

    //Create boxes
    for(var j = 1; j < 4; j++) {
        block.box[j] = {
          id : j,
          content : '<span>html for box' + j + '</span>'
       }
    }

    blocks[i] = block;
}
```